# Jenkins: start writing log for all of existing/new jobs

Tags: jenkins, logging

I have started to use [Job log logger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-log-logger-plugin/) plugin for Jenkins to write job log, but it requires to go through each existing/new job to select this option.
So is there any way(plugin or something else) to do this at once for all of existing/new jobs?

Comment: Use system groovy to iterate and set, but seems like a really bad idea to replicate all your job logs into the Jenkins system log.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Could you mention why is it not a good idea, and maybe there is another option? Then I'm going to capture all the generated logs to LogInsight.

Comment: I am not familiar with Job log logger (a 10 yr old plugin) or LogInsight, which you did not mention, but the logs from the jobs tell you what happened in a job (ie: how did the build go). The Job logger appends that into the Jenkins systems logs, which tells you how Jenkins is doing; If you want to pull in the build logs or build performance data, do that directly from the jobs. If you want to monitor Jenkins, that's the system (and agent) logs. Content is Apples and Oranges. I have 8000 jobs, with ~1000 runs /day across dozens of agents, largest build logs get up to 1GB per run; killer.